# defining an image element in DTD

Tags: xml, dtd, xmetal

I have created a specilized DTD for XMetal, in which the image element is added.

the structure of the image element is as follows

```
<!ENTITY  % Attr-com
    "id ID #IMPLIED
    class NMTOKEN #IMPLIED
    type NMTOKEN #IMPLIED
    style CDATA #IMPLIED
    lang NMTOKEN #IMPLIED"
>

<!ELEMENT image EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST image  %Attr-com; 
            alt    CDATA    #IMPLIED
            href    CDATA   #REQUIRED
            keyref  NMTOKEN #IMPLIED
            border  CDATA   #IMPLIED
            height  CDATA   #IMPLIED
            width   CDATA   #IMPLIED
            align   CDATA   #IMPLIED
            scale   NMTOKEN #IMPLIED
            placement  (inline | break)        "inline"
            conref CDATA   #IMPLIED>
```

But this doesn't work in Xmetal. The image icon in Xmetal is not highlighting. If I use the image element from the element list, it will show like this

```
<image/>
```

How to use this DTD in Xmetal, so that the images should able to add.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used XMetaL in a looong time but I still have an install and can show you how I've always done graphics.

All of your attributes are either CDATA or NMTOKEN so there's no way for XMetaL to know what the actual image is.

What I do is make one of the attributes an ENTITY type. This will make XMetaL look for an entity declaration with a name that matches the value of the attribute.

The entity should be declared as an NDATA (notational data) system entity. You will also need to make sure the notation is declared. For my example, I'm using a png.

Here's an example of my DTD and XML.

**DTD**

```
<!NOTATION PNG PUBLIC "PNG 1.0" "image/png">
<!ELEMENT doc (p|image)+>
<!ELEMENT p (#PCDATA)>
<!ELEMENT image EMPTY>
<!ATTLIST image
    href ENTITY #REQUIRED>
```

**XML**

```
<!DOCTYPE doc SYSTEM "test.dtd" [
<!ENTITY test.png SYSTEM "images/test.png" NDATA PNG>
]>
<doc>
<p>Test image:</p>
<image href="test.png"/>
</doc>
```

Note: My XML has an internal subset that contains an entity declaration for my image. You don't have to add these manually; you can use "Tools" -> "Graphic Entities..." in XMetaL:

[image]

Here's my XML open in XMetaL:

[image]

If you notice, my cursor is after the `image` element and inside of the `doc` closing tag. Since the `image` element is allowed at this location, the image button in the toolbar is active and will allow me to add a new image. This is what it looks like if I add a new image:

[image]

To choose an actual image, you can edit the `href` attribute in the Attribute Inspector. It is a dropdown that lists all of the available entities you have declared.

Hopefully this is enough to get you going. If not let me know what is still not working.

Answer (score 0):

In general, you can configure XMetaL to recognize a DTD's image element(s) by using the CTM file that is part of the XMetaL customization associated with the DTD. Note that this is an *alternative* to using XML entities to represent graphics in XMetaL; with the CTM it is not necessary to use entities and the ENTITY attribute type.

There is general information about XMetaL's CTM file available here:
http://xmetal.com/tutorials/customizing_xmetal_manually.html
Search for "<Images>" on that page to find exactly the bit about identifying image types in XMetaL.

However (speaking to the specific question here), it looks as if you are using DITA. When you use a specialized DITA DTD, XMetaL should be automatically generating a correct CTM for you; you should not need to edit the CTM yourself. Thus it is possible that your question actually is an XMetaL support issue.

It appears that you posted a similar question on the XMetaL Community Forum, and we (I work at JustSystems, makers of XMetaL) have been assisting you in that thread. At this point I will let the assistance continue there:

http://forums.xmetal.com/index.php/topic,3355.0.html